# numpy-thonic way to store data on already-allocated data

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a code where I have to iterate creation of several `GB` of data with `np.tile` and `np.repeat`.
After few iterations the code goes out of memory. Since each tile and repeat is used only within inside an iteration, I am thinking on how to save memory.

Ideally, in order to reuse memory, I would like to do something like this:

```py
large_matrix = np.zeros(N*M)

for data in generator:
    
    np.repeat(data, M, out = large_matrix)
    [...] #here I will use large matrix
```

Unfortunately there is no such keyword `out` on `np.repeat` and I had create my own `njit(parallel=True)` `numba` functions to replicate numpy repeat function.

However, before I start rewriting many other numpy functions in numba, my question is: what is the numpy-thonic way to store numpy results on already existing arrays so to keep memory usage under control?

Answer (score 0):

1. Numpy's in-place assignment is `large_matrix[:]=np.repeat(data,M)`
2. better - encapsulate the inside of your for-loop as a function (e.g. `def process(data):`). This way, all matrices except for the returned outputs are freed when the iteration is done. If the outputs are big, write them down to disk instead of accumulating them on RAM.
3. It's very rare that tile or repeat can't be replaced with smart broadcasting.